# Ebay VerifyAddItem, Error Code: 10009

Tags: python, python-2.7, ebay-api

First of all I'm using [ebaysdk](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python). My problem is when I try to add a new item ebay gives me the following error:

> u'VerifyAddItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 10009, No
>    exists or  is specified as an empty
>   tag. No  exists or  is specified as an
>   empty tag in the request., Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code:
>   10009, No  exists or  is specified as an
>   empty tag. No  exists or  is specified as
>   an empty tag in the request., Class: RequestError, Severity: Error,
>   Code: 10009, No  exists or
>    is specified as an empty tag. No
>    exists or  is specified
>   as an empty tag in the request.'

My **problem** is I gave every parameter, but the api claims that I'm not.

```
....
<Currency>USD</Currency>
<Country>US</Country>
<ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly VerifyAddItem call will not be used to add items to eBay. This call is used just to check whether the data you are sending is valid or not. In order to add items to eBay us the call AddItems and AddFixedPriceItem.

Coming to your issue , You might have missed any required fields in the XML . Please check the XML structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VerifyAddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
 <RequesterCredentials>
   <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
 </RequesterCredentials>
 <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
 <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
 <Item>
   <Title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</Title>
   <Description>
     This is the first book in the Harry Potter series. In excellent condition!
   </Description>
   <PrimaryCategory>
     <CategoryID>377</CategoryID>
   </PrimaryCategory>
   <StartPrice>1.0</StartPrice>
   <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
   <ConditionID>4000</ConditionID>
   <Country>US</Country>
   <Currency>USD</Currency>
   <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
   <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
   <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
   <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
   <PayPalEmailAddress>magicalbookseller@yahoo.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
   <PictureDetails>
     <PictureURL>http://i1.sandbox.ebayimg.com/03/i/00/30/07/20_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>
   </PictureDetails>
   <PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <ReturnPolicy>
     <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
     <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
     <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
     <Description>If you are not satisfied, return the book for refund.</Description>
     <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
   </ReturnPolicy>
   <ShippingDetails>
     <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
     <ShippingServiceOptions>
       <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
       <ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>
       <ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>
     </ShippingServiceOptions>
   </ShippingDetails>
   <Site>US</Site>
 </Item>
</VerifyAddItemRequest>
```

Go through this link http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/VerifyAddItem.html to check the required fields for this call.